# using dictionary as switch case in python got error "str" obj is not callable

Tags: python, dictionary

1.it gives an error "**str**" obj is not callable.how do i solve this one ?

```
def oper(x):
        def display():
            print("hello")

        def pop():
            print("hi")


        def push():

            print(int(input("enter the value")))


        switcher = {
            1:push ,
            2:pop,
            3:display,
            4:"exit"
        }

        switcher.get(x,"invalid choice")()
        return
    print(' 1-push \n 2-pop \n 3-display \n 4-exit \n')
    while True:
        a=int(input("enter your choice:"))
        oper(a)

        break
```

OUTPUT:-

```
 1-push 
 2-pop 
 3-display 
 4-exit 

enter your choice:4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Desai/PycharmProjects/stac/venv/Include/stac.py", line 28, in <module>
    oper(a)
  File "C:/Users/Desai/PycharmProjects/stac/venv/Include/stac.py", line 23, in oper
    switcher.get(x,"invalid choice")()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

OR i have tried out this code as well but does not give proper output
when i gave input as " **1**" or "**2**" or "**3**" it executes all the three functions **display(), pop(),push()**.How can i solve this stuff?

```
def oper(x):
    def display():
        print("hello")
    def pop():
        print("hi")
    def push(g):
         print(g)

    switcher = {
        1:push(int(input("enter the value"))) ,
        2:pop(),
        3:display(),
        4:"exit"
    }

    switcher.get(x,"invalid choice")
    return
print(' 1-push \n 2-pop \n 3-display \n 4-exit \n')
while True:
    a=int(input("enter your choice:"))
    oper(a)

    break
```

> OUTPUT:-

```
 1-push 
 2-pop 
 3-display 
 4-exit 

enter your choice:1
enter the value1
    1
    hi
    hello

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

[python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBl7C.png)

[run time error "str" obj is not callable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3uRf.png)

Comment: Please post actual code and error messages, not images so people can copy it and run it/debug it.

Comment: Your images are too low resolution to be readable

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: If you want simply to exit from program, you can do `4:exit`

Comment: Hey :) First three keys in `switcher` dict have function reference as a value which is ok to be called later in the code on line `switcher.get(x,"invalid choice")()`. However the last key has string "exit" as a value and therefore cannot be called as a function `"exit"()`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the following line, you are calling whatever `switcher.get(x, 'invalid choice')` returns.

```
switcher.get(x, 'invalid choice')()
```

But, when the input is `4`, the `switcher` will return a string, i.e. `'exit'`. And then the returned string is being called by the `()`. This is not allowed. Better create another function that prints exit.

**Edit 1:** *Possible solution*

```
def display():
    print("Hello\n")

def pop():
    print("Hi\n")

def push():
    user_input = input("\nEnter a value: ")
    print('Entered value: {}\n'.format(user_input))

switcher = {
            '1': push,
            '2': pop,
            '3': display,
        }

print('1- push\n2- pop\n3- display\n4- exit\n')

while True:
    a = input("Enter your choice: ")
    if a == '4':
        print('Exiting...')
        break
    elif a not in list(switcher.keys()):
        print('\nInvalid input. Try again.\n')
    else:
        switcher.get(a)()
```

Comment: remove the quotes for `exit` in `switcher`.

Comment: but i want to display "exit"

Comment: and i have also tried to code it in another way but it also gives an error .please check it above.and plz help me out

Comment: I have edited my post and have added one possible way of getting your desired output. You will have to explore any further improvements in this.

Comment: vineet bhat thank u very much for your effort and did u saw the another code  i have shared .can u plz tell me whats an error in that code

Comment: If you place function calls within a dictionary like, `pop()`, `display()` etc, then if you only write `switcher`, all the functions will get executed. The program never reaches the `.get(x, "invalid input")` part. This happens because a dictionary is evaluated as soon as it is referenced.